# PHP dropdown menu populating from mysql not working

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli

I've spent hours reading and trying to figure out why this is not working but the drop down menu does not populate. I think it's something simple but I just cannot see it. Anyone?

dbconn.php

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME' , 'artprints');
define('DB_USER' , 'root');
define('DB_PASS' , '');
define('DB_HOST' , 'localhost');
```

func.php

```
<?php

include_once 'dbconn.php';

function connect(){
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die ('Could not connect to the database' . mysl_error());
    mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);
}

function close(){
    mysql_close();
}

function query(){
    $myData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artists");
    while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
    echo '<option value="' . $record['artistID'] . '">' . $record['artistID'] . '</option>';
    }
}
```

test.php

```
<?php
 include_once 'func.php';
 connect();
 ?>

 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Drop down testing</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <select name='artist'>
 <?php query() ?>
 </select>
 <?php close() ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Please post error messages

Comment: `var_dump($myData);` please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mixing `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*`

`mysqli_connect` and `mysqli_select_db`

against

`mysql_query` and `mysql_fetch_array`

Comment: That's a reason why we would rather use PDO

Comment: and he forgot `;` after function call (`query() and close()`).

Comment: davidkonrad, you're my hero, thanks!
Brewal, I'm investigating PDO now, I am reasonably new to PHP and didn't even know this existed.
q0re, you're right although it works without them? As a matter of better coding practice I assume they are required and will use them in future.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste this in your function.php

```
include_once ('dbconn.php');

function connect()
{
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die ('Could not connect to the database' . mysl_error());
    mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);
}

function close(){
    mysqli_close();
}

function query(){
    $myData = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM artists");
    while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
    echo '<option value="' . $record['artistID'] . '">' . $record['artistID'] . '</option>';
    }
}
```